# Avoid symmetrical safe area when designing with iPhone X in mind

Tags: autolayout, iphone-x

Ponder holding iPhone X in landscape.

As the safe area seems to be symmetrical, the inset of the safe area is as big on the left side as on the right side, regardless which side the notch is on.

Assume that we would want to have the safe area stretch further to the screen edge on the side where the notch is not on. Anyone got a good approach for that? I assume that we would want something that works with autolayout.

[image]

Here the notch is on the left side. We would like to have the margin on the other side smaller, because it feels like we could display more contents there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's possible to do this, Apple advises that you don't do it in their [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/):

> Inset essential content to prevent clipping. In general, **content
>   should be centered and symmetrically** inset so it looks great in any
>   orientation and isn't clipped by corners or the device's sensor
>   housing, or obscured by the indicator for accessing the Home screen.
>   For best results, use standard, system-provided interface elements and
>   Auto Layout to construct your interface. All apps should adhere to the
>   safe area and layout margins defined by UIKit, which ensure
>   appropriate insetting based on the device and context. The safe area
>   also prevents content from underlapping the status bar, navigation
>   bar, toolbar, and tab bar.

That said - I totally understand wanting to use that extra space!

In trying to understand this part of the HIG, let's put it this way: if you have a game that you're watching in landscape, the controls should be symmetrical, so that whether the user is holding the game in `landscapeLeft` or `landscapeRight`, the button is inset by the same amount. If you implement your controls asymmetrically, then the user's muscle memory won't match in one orientation vs another.

You can hear Mike Stern (Design Evangelist at Apple) talk through this concept in the WWDC video from Fall 2017 title ["Designing for iPhone X"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/801/?time=546). (This link has a timestamp where Mike discusses landscape symmetry in detail.)

Comment: Thanks. I've watched that video. I do have a use case that I'm sure most people would agree with. Maybe. Anyway we have a chat in our landscape app - the chat is a table view running from top to bottom and is tied to right side of the screen. The space is kind of limited so, until now, we let the chat text run almost all the way to the right edge of the screen before folding to the next line. For this to look good on the iPhone X we need to uncheck the "Insets To Safe Area" of the table view. Works well in landscape right, but in landscape left, where the notch comes to the right, the notch ..

Comment: runs over the table view rows, of course. So we need to check "Insets To Safe Area" so it looks good in landscape left. But then landscape right is horribly inset, creating a huge waste of white space in our layout. Not wanting to branch off our design, I guess being able to have asymmetrical auto layout, or something, would be better in this case. I do despise iPhone X but yeah :-P

Comment: Many years later...  I forgot that I should've ticked this right. Essential content should of course be within the safe area in pretty much all cases, or it wouldn't be essential content.